# Screen freeze after giving permission to run exe

Tags: windows-7, freeze

My laptop has been having a bit of a problem. I'm asking why, and how to fix it, if possible.

It has windows 7, which was recently installed, because I was given the computer. The problem came with the laptop; my actions didn't cause it.

So, every single time I am asked to give an executable permission to run, (the screen dims and the small permission window pops up, center-screen) and I allow it to run, the following happens:

- The permission window disappears
- The screen remains dimmed
- The mouse continues to respond (so the screen isn't really frozen...)
- The computer remains unresponsive (clicking elicits no action, icons don't light up when I hover over the taskbar, etc.)

If press CTRL+ALT+DEL, though, the expected five options appear, and if I click 'Task Manager', the computer returns to the previous screen with a task manager window in front of any others. So, my laptop resumes regular function, running the executable I gave permission to run.

Things generally function properly, until I run another exe. This freezing is predictable, it happens every time after I give an exe permission to run. Really, it always happens after I close any windows pop-up that dims the screen.

I don't know what other info to provide, because I have no clue what might be malfunctioning. There are no error messages.

Any response is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The permission dialogue and screen dimming are part of User Account Control, a Windows 7 feature that I personally find more annoying than helpful.

While I cannot offer any help on why UAC is freezing your laptop, I can tell you how to disable UAC.

From the Start Menu, go to the Control Panel and into User Accounts and Family Safety (or just User Accounts if you're using a list view).

Once you're in User Accounts, select your account.  If there is only one account you may skip this step.

At the bottom of the list shown on your account's page, there will be Change User Account Control settings.

Click Change User Account Control settings and drag the slider all the way down to Never Notify.

Click OK.

A UAC dialogue will appear asking you if you wish to let UAC make changes to UAC.  Allow it and you shouldn't have your laptop frozen by User Account Control again.

While writing this it occurred to me that if your laptop does not have a GPU, that Windows Aero might be taxing the CPU or integrated graphics enough to freeze the machine.

Comment: Hmm. Well, I have a GPU, but it's quite lame. Anyways, thanks!