# Computer crashes frequently whenever I try to run a .exe file before the system asks permission to run

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, freeze, windows-installer

I have Windows 8.1 in my laptop which has an unusual problem of freezing or not responding when I try to run an .exe file.

As soon as I run it the screen returns to desktop and dims down a bit. Before this issue started to occur when I run an .exe file, the screen dims and the permission window appears which is normal, but recently the popup isn't appearing and instead the computer freezes for around 10 minutes.

My problem is similar to that as in [Screen freeze after giving permission to run exe](https://superuser.com/questions/871390/screen-freeze-after-giving-permission-to-run-exe) .I tried every solution I found but it just didn't work.

Any response will be helpful!

Comment: Does it freeze regardless of UAC mode? (That is, if you disable the dimming so that the permission window appears on the normal desktop, does it freeze anyway?)

Comment: Well, I tried to disable the UAC setting but it also had a popup for assurance, which also had the same problem of freezing.

Comment: Well yes, because during that time you haven't disabled anything _yet_ – the changes will only take effect _after_ you confirm the last change (presumably the system manages to unfreeze after 10 minutes?) You don't need to disable UAC completely, only choose the "Do not dim desktop" mode.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will try

Comment: Is it one specific `.exe` ?

Comment: I dont know whether its same for all the systems but unfortunately that setting also has the popup it seems, it too asked for permissions and lead to same issue.

Comment: Yes, I tried to install many different exe files, it didn't work .I recently wanted to install git bash but I wasn't able to successfully install it due to this issue.

Comment: Well you cant say *"...freezing or not responding when I try to run an* ***.exe file."*** . Every application on windows when ran, starts to run in form of a exe. Your browser is even on the same fact. So be more clear

Comment: What I mean by that is when I install new software, it freezes. @Neptotech -vishnu