# Can we install git bash other than the in the .exe form, that is like in a zip file?

Tags: installation, git, zip

I am facing an issue which makes it difficult for me to install git bash in .exe format -[Computer crashes frequently whenever I try to run a .exe file before the system asks permission to run](https://superuser.com/questions/1748726/computer-crashes-frequently-whenever-i-try-to-run-a-exe-file-before-the-system?noredirect=1#comment2713180_1748726). So is there a way to install git bash from a zip file or any other format . I just want a clarification whether that is possible . Sorry if my question doesn't make sense, I am new to these stuff.

Any response will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a solution that does not start an exe, but the closest I could find was the portable edition. This exe is an 7zip package that automatically unpacks itself to a location. It can be found on the [Git download page for Windows](https://git-scm.com/download/win)

The git download page for Windows appears to give the option to use the winget tool.
According to that you could do: `winget install --id Git.Git -e --source winget`. Disadvantages to this though is that you need to have winget installed, which might not be the case. Another one, it might still try to start a similar installer, which might not solve the problem.

Another option might be Chocolatey. Searching for [`git`](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages?q=git) shows that it is available as a Choco package. Again, same cons in might start similar installer and you need to have Chocolatey preinstalled.

I think however that the best bet would be to solve the issue with the crashing exe

Comment: Sadly it didn't work, I searched numerous forums and researched deeply but didn't get across any viable solution.